# jQuery Autocomplete using URL

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, scriptaculous

I've been working on a site that currently uses Prototype+Scriptaculous's [Ajax.Autocomplete](http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/ajax-autocompleter/). It works great at the moment, but I need to convert it to jQuery.

I know that **jQueryUI** has an [Autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), but I can't see if there's a way to use the existing external URL without needing to change it.

With Scriptaculous's Ajax.Autocomplete it's extremely simple:

```
new Ajax.Autocompleter('inputID', 'destinationID', 'search.php', {
    paramName: 'q',
    minChars: 2,
    frequency: 0.4,
    indicator: 'loading'
    });
```

It's almost self-explanatory: *inputID* is the ID of the `<input>`, *destinationID* is the element you want the results to be displayed in. *search.php* is the page that returns the results from your database -- including the HTML you want displayed in the list.

The rest of the options should be pretty obvious :)

`search.php?q=search-query` current returns nicely formatted HTML like this:

```
<ul>
    <li id="ID">Result</li>
    <li id="ID">Result</li>
    <li id="ID">Result</li>
</ul>
```

It would be great if I could just use this with the jQueryUI Autocomplete, but I don't know if it's possible (and if it is, how to do it).

I've looked through a bunch of tutorials on using jQueryUI's Autocomplete, but they all seem to focus on either either using a Javascript array (useless to me, since I have thousands of records to search through in a database), or JSON (which I'm hoping to avoid if possible).

Can it be done?

Comment: The jquery autocomplete example for remote access is here: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote Why do you wish to avoid JSON? Assumably your script has an array that it currently outputs as an HTML list.  Why not just output it as a JSON array?

Comment: I was just hoping to avoid rewriting the existing code as much as possible. The client hasn't asked for this, I just don't want to leave the site using both Prototype *and* jQuery -- which it is at the moment :-/

Comment: @dnagirl Thanks. Yes, it just means processing the data twice: Once for JSON and then again out of JSON and into HTML. Keeping it one step would be simpler -- although I guess not by much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: Manual jQuery**

Please try this code, I did not test it, so there might be a bug or two.
Also this assumes /search.php is on the same domain. Edit values in settings as you require

> $(function () {
>
> ```
>    var debounce;
>
>    var settings = {
>        input: '#inputID',
>        dest: '#destID',
>        url: '/search.php?q=',
>        minLength: 2,
>        debounceDelay: 200
>    }
>
>    $(settings.input).on('keyup', function () {
>        var q = this.value;
>
>        if (debounce) clearTimeout(debounce);
>
>        if (q && q.length >= settings.minLength)
>        {
>            debounce = setTimeout(function () {doSearch(q);},
>                                  settings.debounceDelay);
>        }
>
>    });
>
>    $(settings.dest).on("click", "li", function (e) {
>        $(settings.input).val($(this).text());
>        $(settings.dest).empty();
>    })
>
>    function doSearch(query) {
>        $(settings.dest).load(settings.url + query);
>    };
> ```
>
> });

---

**JSON Approach**

have a look at twitter's typeahead, just recently released.  (not be confused with bootstrap's typeahead, this is completely standalone and only requires jquery)

http://twitter.github.com/typeahead.js/

It behaves just like google's searchbox

- autocomplete
- autosuggest
- keyboard support
- multiple sources, both local and remote
- result caching (localStorage) & request throttling
- template support (requires a [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) compatible templating engine, e.g [Hogan](http://twitter.github.com/hogan.js/))

If you need any explanation on how to use it, check the [examples](http://twitter.github.com/typeahead.js/examples/) or comment below

Comment: This uses JSON, making it exactly the same as the jQuery solution...?

Comment: I was hoping you would give JSON a try, perhaps i should have specified that. If all you need is to perform an ajax request and put the results in a <ul> then you can do that with a few lines of jquery. I can provide a basic example of that if you wish

Comment: If that's my only option, I'll certainly accept your answer if you can. Thanks!

Comment: fixed a couple of typos too

Comment: This obviously works OK, but there's nothing to actually allow the user to select something from the list :)

Comment: I updated the answer to include a simple click handler on the <li> you load. This is meant to be a basic example, therefore I will not be providing keyboard integration. For anything more advanced, please use one of the plugins suggested

Comment: I ended up just writing it myself and using JSON. Thanks for the help, though.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, since you don't wish to output JSON, try this:

```
var aclist = [];
$('input#myauto').autocomplete({
  source: aclist,
  change: function( event, ui ) {
              $.ajax({
                  url: 'search.php',
                  data: {
                      'inputID': inputID,
                      'destinationID': destinationID
                  },
                  dataType: 'html',
                  success: function (html) {
                      aclist = [];
                      $('li', html).each(function () {
                          aclist.push({
                              value: this.id,
                              label: $(this).text()
                          });
                      });
                  },
                  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                      aclist = [];
                  }
              });
  }
});
```

I haven't debugged it, but essentially the idea to to link an ajax call to the onChange event and translate the html returned by that call into an array of the proper format.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think Dogoku beat you to it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery autocomplete and use a function as the source, then on that function make your ajax call and parse the html from your script to an javascript array

Have a look at the jquery docs for autocomplete source property http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source